# Virus:Windows 7 user/drivers/configuration was reset

Tags: virus

Last night I went to sleep without turning off my computer. When I wake up I found out that all my configuration, video, sound, Windows user customizations, all was reset. Now I have no sound, video is crappy, I can just use the Windows classic theme, I even had the English language pack installed, but now it appears in Spanish which is the original language of my installation. For the video I don't know what is happening, Windows does not allow me to use any "cool" theme, but S

Does anybody knows of a virus that could be causing this problem? or is it a way to restore my previous configuration?

I am running Windows 7 Professional

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be infected

Follow the order given below to properly disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advise and let you know the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [**System Restore**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11238/using-system-restore-to-recover-your-windows-7-computer/) to restore your computer to a previous state.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the PC has suffered a power fail overnight and restarted. Do a disk check first.

Comment: How can I check that? Do that could have caused all the symptoms?

Comment: Right-click on Computer and choose Manage.  Go to Storage > Disk Management.  Right-click on your C drive, choose properties.  Go to the Tools tab, and select Check Now, under Error Checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting first, you may be running in safe mode (which would account for your hardware settings) or it has loaded the last know good configuration following an event such as a power fail. In any event, run the error checking tool on your system disk. (Open Explorer, right-click on the C drive, Properties, Tools, Error checking.

Comment: I did reboot, but didn't help. Thanks, I will look at the Error checking thing.